# Can a Bloodclaw Master stack Superior TWF with Improved/Greater TWF?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Does the Bloodclaw Master ability Superior Two-Weapon Fighting interact in any way with the benefits of Improved and/or Greater Two-Weapon Fighting in terms of attack bonus modifiers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. When you fight with two weapons, you take a penalty on all of the attacks you make during your turn, including the ones you gain from Improved Two-Weapon Fighting and Greater Two-Weapon Fighting. If you're using a light weapon in your off-hand and you have the Two-Weapon Fighting feat, the penalty is only -2. Superior Two-Weapon Fighting reads:

> Starting at 2nd level, when you attack with two daggers or Tiger Claw
>   weapons, you do not take the –2 penalty on attack rolls for fighting
>   with two weapons.

In other words, Superior Two-Weapon Fighting eliminates the penalty for fighting with two weapons provided those weapons are daggers or Tiger Claw weapons. Remember, the Tiger Claw weapons are the kukri, kama, handaxe, unarmed strike, and claw.

To give you an example of how Two-Weapon Fighting normally works, assume you have a character with a base attack bonus of 11 and the feats Two-Weapon Fighting, Improved Two-Weapon Fighting and Greater Two-Weapon Fighting. When this character uses the full-attack action to fight with two weapons and his off-hand weapon is light, he would get six attacks: three with his primary weapon (one at BAB-2, one at his BAB-7, and one at his BAB-12) and three with his off-hand (again, one at his BAB-2, one at his BAB-7, and one at his BAB-12).*

If our two-weapon slicer and dicer also had Superior Two-Weapon Fighting and was using daggers or Tiger Claw weapons, the -2 penalty from two-weapon fighting with a light weapon in his off-hand would go away. He would still get three attacks with each hand. However, the first attack from each hand would be at his full BAB, the second would be at his BAB-5, and the third would be at his BAB-10. In other words, all of his attacks would be more accurate.